# External HDD becomes unkown

Tags: filesystem, external-hdd, filemanager, unknown-device

Today, all of a sudden, my external HDD is no longer recognized as a file system and ubuntu sees it as 'unknown'. How do I resolve this? I'm fine with formatting it if necessary.

```
Model: SAMSUNG HM100UI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 
----------------------------------------------------------
Number | Start | End  | Size | Type  | File system | Flags
1      | 32,3kb|1000GB|1000GB|primary| fat32       | lba
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Kind regards,

S

Comment: Can you add the output of running `sudo parted -l` in a terminal while the HDD is connected to your question please?

Comment: Okay, added the output to the question.

Comment: Can you run `sudo file -s /dev/sdf` and add the output of that as well?